# C# Downloading Program (Array)

Tags: c#, web, download, webclient

I have a problem with my code. I want to download some files (I'm currently doing a patcher), but there are so many files, and I don't want to create a string for all of them.

I want to store the links in an array. But the debugger says there's and exception in `WebClient`. Here's my code (`fájlNév` means `fileName` and `fájlNévAlap` means `baseFileName`): UPDATED CODE:

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->

        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        string[] remoteUrl = new string[2] { "https://www.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/", " https://www.dropbox.com/s/spni307vmk4zng9/" };
        string[] fájlNév = new string[2] { "alut.dll", "DevIL.dll" };
        string fájlNévAlap = "BlackBox.dll", WebResource = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < remoteUrl.Length; i++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < fájlNév.Length; x++) {
                WebResource = remoteUrl[i] + fájlNév[x];
                MessageBox.Show(WebResource);
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(WebResource,fájlNév[x]);
            }
        }
```

What can I do? What is wrong?

Comment: What the heck kind of variable name is `fájlNév`?

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown by your code?

Comment: @MikeChristensen it's a `string[]`

Comment: @MikeChristensen It means filename in Hungarian.

Comment: @Xantham - Well I guess if everyone working on the project has Hungarian keyboards, who am I to argue.  Anyway, my guess is it's a permission issue writing to the root drive.  I wish they'd share the exception.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I just used translate.google.com with Autodetect language.

Comment: @Mike Yeah maybe a System.Security due to missing admin privileges.

Comment: Shouldn't the slashes in the URL be escaped, or at least with the @ to auto-escape?  Or are URLs treated differently?

Comment: Can't you all just wait for the exception text?

Comment: @Xantham I don't see any backslashes in the URL

Comment: @Xantham, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) example shows no escape.

Comment: I hate it when the OP doesn't respond

Comment: @Ofiris it's enough to point to the documentation about escaping in string literals, URLs are not a specific case

Comment: @wRAR Good point.  But there is also the matter of the (Websource,"C://") which appears to be a pseudo-escaped forwardslash.  Shouldn't it be an escaped backslash?

Comment: @Xantham no idea. Forward slashes in paths are OK at least in some cases.

Comment: as a Hungarian: `fájlNév`=`fileName`, `fájlNévAlap`=`baseFileName`

Comment: Oh, sorry, the exception is 404 not found. I have tested out the links, they are working.

Answer (score 4):

Many comments but not one mentioned this,

check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public void DownloadFile(
    string address,
    string fileName
)
```

`DownloadFile` expect a file-name and not a folder.

Try changing to:

```
myWebClient.DownloadFile(WebResource,"C://"  + fájlNév[x])
```

Moreover, writing directly to root folder might cause security exception, might be a good practice to write to a specific folder.

---

In addition, Xantham noted the loop will cause array out of bound exception.

Comment: Thanks for this, but still not works. There's a 404 not found. I have tested out the links, they are working.

Comment: Do you need to be authenticated to dropbox ?
Try it with another link, not dropbox one. see if it works.

Comment: I have deleted it, now it has 404 with the dropbox. I have tryed it without arrays, works with dropboxs, so I have some problem in the array part.

Comment: It seems like you edited your code, can't help without seeing it.

Comment: Hmm. I have tested it out with MessageBox.Show(WebResource), and it's correct in the first loop part, but in the second "link", the first part (remoteUrl) didn't changed. (So, first, I've got "https://www.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/alut.dll", and in the second part, I've got https://www.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/DevIL.dll" So, I don't know why, but it can't loop correctly in the "i" part. (remoteUrl) (Code updated, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

Ofiris gave the main answer that a file-name is necessary, however there is a more mundane problem as well that I thought should be brought to attention.

The initial calls to the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= remoteUrl.Length; i++)
```

and

```
for(int x = 0; x <= fájlNév.Length; x++)
```

They will cause an array out of bounds exception as well, when it will try to look at remoteUrl[2], in an array of only 2 objects (0 and 1).